# javascript check file name only English character

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need a way to check that the file selected has only English characters as if it is uploaded in different language it is changed to ??? causing 404 not found.

I have tried this but it doesn't work , this is part from my code where file.name i use it to show the name of the file

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/;

if (regex.test(file.name.value)) {
  return true;
} 
else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a filename it doesn't work on?  And in what way does it not work - is it allowing foregin characters through or is it denying valid names?  If the file name is the full name it will usually include a dot for isntance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/;

  if (regex.test(file.name)) {
   return true;
  } 
    else {
      return false;
    }
```

use file.name instead of file.name.value as you said it show the name of the file

Answer (score 0):

If the file name is the full name it will usually have an extensiona nd therefore include a dot.  Try:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\. ]{2,30}$/;
```

Comment: thank you as @ramy said i should use file.name instead of file.name.value